# In React-Native FlatList onScroll event is not getting called

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, onscroll

FlatList onScroll event is not firing at all for the below code:

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList 
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} 
      data={data} 
      onScroll={() => { 
        console.log('test');
        Keyboard.dismiss; //FlatList is not firing onScroll event 
      }} 
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => ( 
        <ListItem item={item} index={index} /> 
      )} 
      keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
    />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: can you show the full code ?

Comment: Updated #Anuj Sharma

Comment: Maybe your  Keyboard.dismiss function is not working....

Comment: This is a known issue. I too got fed up trying many solutions. It fires in IOS but not in android. I ended up using onEndReached as per my requirement.

Comment: The onScroll event itself is not getting called as even the console.log is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

Use the

> OnEndReached

function of flatlist. If you use onScroll in Flatlist then sometimes its not working for the android, but for iOS it works. Let see my code below:

```
        <FlatList
            // style = {{marginBottom: 100}}
            data={feedbacks}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={f => f._id.toString()}
            renderItem={renderFeedback}
            onEndReached={() => console.log("End reached")}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            // onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => { // not working on android
            //  if (!loading && isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
            //    setPageNo(page=> page+1)
            //  }
            //   }}
            // scrollEventThrottle={500}
            ListFooterComponent={() => loading ?
                <ActivityIndicator
                    style={{ padding: 15 }}
                    size="large"
                    color={colors.primary}
                />
                : null
            }
        />
```